# Two steps induction in Lean4: how to obtain 2nd inductive hypothesis?

Tags: lean4, beginner

When trying to solve this example from "The Mechanics of Proof":

```
def a : ℕ → ℤ
  | 0 => 2
  | 1 => 1
  | n + 2 => a (n + 1) + 2 * a n

example (n : ℕ) : a n = 2 ^ n + (-1) ^ n := by
  two_step_induction n with k IH1 IH2
  . calc a 0 = 2 := by rw [a]
      _ = 2 ^ 0 + (-1) ^ 0 := by numbers
  . calc a 1 = 1 := by rw [a]
      _ = 2 ^ 1 + (-1) ^ 1 := by numbers
  calc
    a (k + 2)
      = a (k + 1) + 2 * a k := by rw [a]
    _ = (2 ^ (k + 1) + (-1) ^ (k + 1)) + 2 * (2 ^ k + (-1) ^ k) := by rw [IH1, IH2]
    _ = (2 : ℤ) ^ (k + 2) + (-1) ^ (k + 2) := by ring
```

using only Mathlib, I am struggling to obtain the inductive hypothesis for the 2nd induction step. For now I have

```
example (n : ℕ) : a n = 2 ^ n + (-1) ^ n := by
  induction n with
  | zero => simp [a]; rfl
  | succ k ik => cases k with
    | zero => simp [a]; rfl
    | succ k => calc
        a (k + 2) = a (k + 1) + 2 * a k := rfl
        _ = (2 ^ (k + 1) + (-1) ^ (k + 1)) + 2 * (2 ^ k + (-1) ^ k) := by rw [ik]; sorry
        _ = 2 ^ (k + 2) + (-1) ^ (k + 2) := by ring
```

But here I only have one inductive hypothesis. Where would I get the other hypothesis (in the example above, we have ih1 and ih2) from?

Comment: Also, at the end of MoP, there is a translation guide to Mathlib Lean code: https://hrmacbeth.github.io/math2001/Mainstream_Lean.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put induction principle `Nat.twoStepInduction` into the `induction'` tactic.  (The `norm_num` tactic is a good replacement for the `numbers` tactic in Mechanics of Proof, although as you noticed, `rfl` also works in this case.)

```
import Mathlib

def a : ℕ → ℤ
  | 0 => 2
  | 1 => 1
  | n + 2 => a (n + 1) + 2 * a n

example (n : ℕ) : a n = 2 ^ n + (-1) ^ n := by
  induction' n using Nat.twoStepInduction with k IH1 IH2
  . calc a 0 = 2 := by rw [a]
      _ = 2 ^ 0 + (-1) ^ 0 := by rfl  -- or norm_num
  . calc a 1 = 1 := by rw [a]
      _ = 2 ^ 1 + (-1) ^ 1 := by rfl  -- or norm_num
  . calc
      a (k + 2)
        = a (k + 1) + 2 * a k := by rw [a]
      _ = (2 ^ (k + 1) + (-1) ^ (k + 1)) + 2 * (2 ^ k + (-1) ^ k) := by rw [IH1, IH2]
      _ = (2 : ℤ) ^ (k + 2) + (-1) ^ (k + 2) := by ring
```

You can also use `Nat.twoStepInduction` with the built in `induction` tactic as follows:

```
example (n : ℕ) : a n = 2 ^ n + (-1) ^ n := by
  induction n using Nat.twoStepInduction
  . rfl
  . rfl
  . case _ k ik1 ik2 => calc
    a (k + 2) = a (k + 1) + 2 * a k := rfl
    _ = (2 ^ (k + 1) + (-1) ^ (k + 1)) + 2 * (2 ^ k + (-1) ^ k) := by rw [ik1, ik2] 
    _ = 2 ^ (k + 2) + (-1) ^ (k + 2) := by ring
```

---

I found the induction principle `Nat.twoStepInduction` via [moogle.ai](https://www.moogle.ai/search/raw?q=two%20step%20induction%20principle).

---

To see why you need `Nat.twoStepInduction`, this is how you would prove it with normal induction.  Notice we are not proving the original statement by induction, but instead the conjunction of both the `n` and `n+1` cases at the same time!  That gives us the necessary induction hypotheses to do the induction, and it is what the induction principle `Nat.twoStepInduction` automates.

```
example (n : Nat) : a n = 2 ^ n + (-1) ^ n := by
  -- prove the `n` and `n+1` cases simultaneously by induction
  have aux_lemma :
      a n = 2 ^ n + (-1) ^ n /\
      a (n + 1) = 2 ^ (n + 1) + (-1) ^ (n + 1) := by
    induction n with
    | zero =>
      constructor
      . rfl
      . rfl
    | succ k ik =>
      constructor
      . exact ik.2
      . calc
        a (k + 2) = a (k + 1) + 2 * (a k) := rfl
        _ = 2 ^ (k + 1) + (-1) ^ (k + 1) + 2 * (2 ^ k + (-1) ^ k) := by rw [ik.1, ik.2]
        _ = 2 ^ (k + 2) + (-1) ^ (k + 2) := by ring

  -- we just need the `n` case in the end
  exact aux_lemma.1
```